# Exchange Server Integration Issue

Tags: exchange-server

After connecting to the exchange server wsdl, it is just allowing to access method listing. but not allowing to access methods.

```
$wsdl = 'https://SERVER_URL/ews/Services.wsdl';
$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => 1,'exceptions' => true,'login' => 'LOGINUSER','password' => 'LOGINPASSWORD')); 
var_dump($soapClient->__getFunctions());
```

How can we get access to the wsdl methods?

Please provide good suggestions for the Exchange  Server 2010.